# Blender UV map unwraps weird?

Tags: uv

I'm working on a model and I've noticed that when I look at others, they don't seem to end up with the same "mess" that I get and I would like to know if there's a way to avoid getting this result?

I don't mind having to fix this manually but I'm mainly curious as to why this happens. The model I'm making is a humanoid creature that's thin, tall and disproportionate.

[image: UV map with problem]

Again, I don't mind having to undo this and I'm mainly curious as to why this happens every time I unwrap a model.

Comment: First make sure your scale is set to 1. Do you have any modifiers messing with your UVs?

Comment: This happen when you add vertexes to unwraped topology. Also check "subdivide UVs" on subdivision modifier.

Comment: How are you unwrapping it? What are the exact steps? Can it be unwrapped using the seams you placed at all?

Comment: Try unwrapping by selecting "UV Smart Project" instead of just "unwrap"

Answer (score 1):

This happens, if

1. you change a model that was already unwrapped by adding geometry.
2. you join separate objects into one mesh while not all of them were unwrapped.
3. you join separate uv-unwrapped objects into one mesh, without adding seams between them.

It might also happen, if you join two separate uv-unwrapped objects with unapplied scales.